# Performing an action when 2 buttons pressed at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to code within swift so that whenever 2 buttons are pressed simultaneously, an action occurs? I can create Action links within Swift for individual buttons when they're pressed but I'm not sure how to create a new action when both buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use a state machine to keep the state of both buttons.

Both buttons can be linked to a single `touchDownInside`. Each time a button triggers that method, increment the state.
Similarly, both buttons can be linked to a single `touchUpInside`. Each time a button triggers this method, decrement the state.

Finally, in `touchDownInside`, check if the state is 2 (when both buttons are pressed). This means that both buttons are pressed simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks Schemtrical. Thats a logical approach and should work. Thanks